# Setting a time as default value in gxt?

Tags: gxt, timefield

I realized I have this with all combo box. I want it to have a default value so I tried...

```
TimeField field = new TimeField();
field.setFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH:mm"));
field.setRawValue("10:00");
```

But when I open the section, the value does not get set. It is still blank.

Answer (score 3):

I m found the solution. I used following format its woks.

```
private TimeField fromTime = new TimeField();
    fromTime.setFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH:mm"));
    fromTime.setIncrement(1);
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setText("00:00");
    fromTime.setValue(time);
    fromTime.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
    toolbar.add(fromTime);
```